# Updating MapView annotations in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I've been racking my brain about this for days. I create a `MapView` in my project that I load with Annotations and pins.

Within the annotation, I have two buttons (upvote and downvote). The buttons do what they are supposed to do, and work fine with the network. However, I cannot get them to update the counter below them to update (pictured below).

So, the question is: **How do I update the text underneath the upvote/downvote buttons dynamically?**

My code to add the pins w/ Annotations:

```
//Add the new pin/annotation to the array
that.state.displayedDrops.splice(0,0, {
    ...
  title: dataSnapshot.val().author,
     //Next line calls a function that returns a <View> hierarchy.
  detailCalloutView: that._getAnnotationView(key, dataSnapshot.val().secret, dataSnapshot.val().author),
    ...
});
```

And the `_getAnnotationView(key, message, author)` function:

```
_getAnnotationView(key, message, author) {
  return(
          ...
    //This state stores the amount of upvotes for the given key
    <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 30}}>{String(this.state["upvotes-".concat(key)])}</Text>
          ...
  );
}
```

And finally, the `upvote(key)` function.

```
upvote(key) {
  var that = this;
     ...
  if(committed) {
     that.setState({
        ["upvotes-".concat(key)]: dataSnapshot,
      });
   }
};
```

[image]